# How to refer to a tabpanels tab, from inside

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a tabpanel which is part of a form (input fields are on different tabs). I need to inform the user on submission if a form has invalid fields even if they are not on the current tab. I think the best way would be to change the tabs color.

The question is how can I get the reference for the tab button, without introducing a new id?

Here is what i was trying to do, turned out to be a dead end since i get reference to the tab inner body, and with one more up to the entire tab panel

```
...
xtype:'tabpanel',
plain:true,
activeTab: 0,
height:190,
margin: '10 0 0 0',
items: [{
    title: 'Personal',
    layout:'column',
    border:false,
    items:[{
        columnWidth:.5,
        border:false,
        layout: 'anchor',
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [{
             fieldLabel: 'Email',
             name: 'user[email]',
             allowBlank: false,
             listeners: {
                 'validitychange': function(th, isvalid, eOpts) {
                     if(!isvalid) {
                         alert(this.up().up().getId());
                     };
                 }
             },
             vtype:'email',
             anchor:'95%'
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Once you get the tab panel, would `getTabBar().items[x]` be what you're looking for?

Comment: `getTabBar().getComponent(x)` was worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:
From your field or any other Component in the panel (like a button) :

```
this.up('tabpanel').down('tab').el.applyStyles('background:red')
```

if the tab in question is not the first tab, you can use any tab property in the selector like this:   ...`down('tab[text=Example]')` . You can use id property if you have it, if not you can just make up any property and set it to something meaningful like "ref:FirstTab".

Comment: I am facing a similar problem, and your solution looks pretty good, but I have a question for you.  I have several tabs where the order is subject to change.  How do I apply a unique itemId to the actual tab and not the container?  In the OP's code for instance, I have `itemId: tabId` in between **Personal** and **column**, but searching for that id returns the container, not the actual tab

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the **tabPanel** then you can access the items of its **tabBar** directly with:

```
this.up('tabpanel').getTabBar().items.get(0)
this.up('tabpanel').getTabBar().items.get(1)
```

etc.

See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.tab.Bar-property-items